# Generic Trie Haskell implementation

Tags: haskell, package, trie

I needed a generic [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) implementation in Haskell but I could not find any.

I was implemented [my own functions](https://gist.github.com/josejuan/5412756) (only keys here, I didn't need data on Trie) but I want to find a good Trie implementation in Haskell for future uses (I'm a rookie haskeller).

I was found Data.Trie but keys are ByteString.

Is Data.Trie the correct option? (and then I don't know how to use it)

Thank you!!! :D

Comment: There's no way to write a trie that works on arbitrary key types. What keys do you want to use? Note that `Data.IntMap` and `Data.IntSet` are tries with `Int` keys.

Comment: C.A. McCann, a Trie only need a type supporting Equality operator over a sequenced source data. With that, you can construct a Trie. What does matter if you don't know underlying type?. Is not my implementation a Trie? Thank you! (But suppose the key type is [a])

Comment: Right, you need the keys to either be some sort of sequence or something you can turn into a sequence. For example, `Data.IntMap` treats an `Int` as a sequence of bits. Being able to sort or index directly on each chunk is nice, but a list of things you can compare for equality is enough. Anyway, there's [a package `list-tries` out there](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-tries) but it always struck me as a bit confusing.

Comment: Ok (excuse me, sometimes I'm incomprehensible :( ). Thank you!!!

Comment: Wow! I'm happy, my own Trie implementation follow list-tries package strategy (I was walking right way) :D :D :D Thanks (can you write a response to vote as solved?) :)

Comment: @C.A.McCann There's nothing inherently problematic with defining tries over near-arbitrary key types. See for example this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.1.6342 AFAIK, the idea is used in Conal's `MemoTrie` package, but for the specific purpose of memoization.

Comment: @kosmikus: Of course, but emphasis on "near". You don't need much, but a trie that's completely polymorphic with no class constraint isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moved from comment by request...

The only very generic trie implementation I know of off the top of my head is [the `list-tries` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-tries). It always struck me as a bit overengineered, but one person's "overcomplicated" is another person's "full-featured", so if it suits your purposes go for it. Also, the package seems to be actively maintained, which is good.

Oh, and since the package didn't state this explicitly anywhere I could see: The "Patricia trie" version is a trie that compresses sequences of single-branch nodes into a single node that stores the common key prefix. So for keys "aabb" and "aabc" you'd get a node with "aab" and then branches "b" and "c". The standard trie always branches one element at a time.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the MemoTrie package [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/conal/MemoTrie).
For background on the simple & beautiful underlying theory, see the Haskell wiki [page on memoization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization), including two papers by Ralf Hinze, one by me, and [some blog posts](http://conal.net/blog/tag/memoization/).

Another trie/memoization package is functor-combo, also [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/functor-combo) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/conal/functor-combo).
This package embodies implementations of ideas described in [*Elegant memoization with higher-order types*](http://conal.net/blog/posts/elegant-memoization-with-higher-order-types/) and other blog posts.

Some other related packages:

- Edward Kmett's [representable-tries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-tries-3.0.2)
- Luke Palmer's [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators)

Comment: Thank you Conal but I can't map your response into my question (my fault, I'm sure). Intuitively I can't understand how I can inspect (inside) a memoized structure, on the other hand, using trie, I can inspect that structure to produce new information (memoization run as a black box). I read your post frecuently but is too hard (like magic) to me :D :D Thank you anyway!!!!

Comment: @josejuan: The "memoized structure" *is* the trie. Memoization is a composition of two phases: `memo = untrie . trie`. The first phase (`trie`) converts a function into a trie, and the second phase converts that trie back into a function. If all you want is memoization, you can treat `memo` as a black box. If you want more inspect and transform the data itself, just intercede after `trie` and before `untrie`. These trie structures are always in `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable`, `Traversable`, and `Monad`, so there's a lot of functionality immediately available to operate on them.

Answer (score 3):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TrieMap was some of my work back in the day.  It's not fully clear to me what *you* mean by "generic," but `TrieMap` supports more-or-less arbitrary (recursive, even!) algebraic data types, e.g. binary trees, as trie keys.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! list-tries is direct to use and as "generic trie" can be used from any other structure (eg. a tree is traversable/sequentiable then, you can use it with list-tries, another one, you can transform a IntTrie to list-trie [Bit]), but your implementation do it explicitly! (I saw your package but I did not realize), I will use in future, sure! :D Thank you!